# Direct/indirect and supervised/unsupervised/reinforcement learning

Tags: machine-learning, artificial-intelligence, reinforcement-learning, supervised-learning, unsupervised-learning

Is there a mapping between direct/indirect and supervised/unsupervised/reinforcement learning? To me it looks like direct learning ≈ supervised learning and indirect learning ≈ reinforcement learning, but I couldn't find a good reference for this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Both direct and indirect learning can be unsupervised (that's how I usually see them), drawing conclusions from existing data alone.

Direct learning refers to hard facts logically implied by the data.  For instance, given a data base on international football competitions, you could inquire who has scored the most international goals, lifetime (Abby Wambach; Ali Daei on the men's side).

Indirect learning refers to inferences drawn from the data.  For instance, given a data base of movie reviews, you could identify clusters of users who rate action movies similarly, and use those correlations to predict how one member might like a particular movie he had not yet seen, but others have rated.

Comment: Thanks for clarification. Can you also recommend a reference for this?

Comment: I just did a browser search on the terms "machine learning", "direct learning", and "indirect learning".  I got a lot of papers that take the phrases as axiomatic, but a couple that gave decent examples and explanations.  You might also try the term "emergent", as that correlates well with conclusions from indirect learning.